# Java resultset.getString() returns 0.0 ,1.0,2.0..etc when i am reading 0,1,2 from excel

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, resultset

Java resultset.getString() returns 0.0 ,1.0,2.0..etc when i am reading 0,1,2 from excel.

i cannot use getInt() because my column will have both numbers and strings.
This issue occurs only with excel not with DB (Oracle) .
Please let  me know your ideas and suggestions.

Thanks,
Satheesha

Comment: Can you put a single quote before the number, save, and try again? What happens if the number is `'2` instead of `2`?

Comment: Hi dasblinkenligh -have tried with this but did not work out.

Comment: So did you get `2.0` again?..

Comment: Yes.I got 2.0 instead of 2.

Comment: Then you parse it as a `double`, and convert that `double` to an `int` in your code.

Comment: In Excel numbers are **always** doubles

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be that the datatype in your excel sheet is a decimal.  If you change it to text or an integer it should work.
Which library are you using to read excel files?

Comment: Hi ,
datatype here is a 'varchar2' (This excel sheet is a extract from oracle DB)